# Jungling on paper (Udyr)

Tags: league-of-legends

I would like, if possible, to represent on paper (excel sheet is acceptable) a mathematical model that would help me determine if I can successfully jungle with a champion using a set of runes, starting equipment, and masteries that will support it at minimum.

A model like this will help players immediately understand what they need to change in terms of runes/equipment/masteries to continue jungling effectively after a patch that nerfs or buffs champions and monster creeps.

This could also be a basis to help understand at which level we can solo dragon, etc.

**UPDATE**: To make things a little bit easier and have a common starting point suppose that I select `Udyr` (with `Phoenix Stance`) as champion and start jungling to the blue golem.

Comment: This is a bit of a mammoth task.

Comment: @danixd It is a tough question, I know. I'll assign a lot of bounty points as soon as I'll have this possibility.

Comment: Why not just practice jungling in a custom game? Do note that the strength of the creeps change per minute as well -- this is going to be hard to model.

Comment: Practice is good to test and validate the build, but I do not have time to do a lot of practice in custom game. In addition to this, if Riot decides to suddenly change magic resistance (for example) of blue golem I have to re-test manually all champions. Of course, if the answer is "not answerable", I will do it.

Comment: @Drake it is definitely answerable. If you do a simplified DPS calculation for each encounter then you can quickly determine whether you will win or not. As a rule of thumb, though, there is always an ability for each champion that should be taken (like Drain for fiddle and Phoenix for Udyr) and equipment (5 health pots + armor)

Comment: However, this is something that definitely needs a program. Paper might only work if you do some serious oversimplification, but that's risky considering how sensitive jungling is with some champions.

Comment: There just seems to many possible outcomes for this to be feasable. Rune combinations (100's, if not 1000's) x Mastery combinations (100's) x Item combinations (100's) x Number of champions x Champions skills x Skill levels x Critical / Dodge chance x Walk speeds x Team member passives (i.e. zilean, Janna) x Constantly changing values of different neutral mob strengths. Something this detailed seems TOO much, and requiring such accurate stats when it comes to jungling seems uncessary when you take into consideration ganks, enemy junglers stealing mobs. Its all very situational.

Comment: @danixd I am not asking for an automatic solver for all possible combinations available. Given a certain set of runes/masteries/equip I would only like to understand if I can kill the blue golem or not. At level 1. Do not consider team member passive.

Comment: This is more than one question, and is therefor too general. If you have a specific question about a specific character we can help you.

Comment: @zzzzBov I fail to see why this is more than one question.

Comment: Are the formulas and data that would be necessary to create such a sheet available? I don't know anything about LoL, but creating this doesn't sound like it'd be too bad if the necessary information has all been discovered. I just wouldn't even know where to start looking.

Comment: i can write a simulation for that if you can give me the data for hploss/manaloss etc for every champion using a set number of skills for a camp. then i think the combination should not be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Wow that is an incredible question to answer. Hasn't someone posted a lengthy review on runes for Udyr at like Mobafire? Because that where I would look. Rune combinations seem to show maximium effectiveness in clusters of 4. One type for each section. like health for seals. armour piercing for marks. Celerity for glyphs and health for quintencess. These are just examples. I would read a bunch of various reviews and make decisions from there. Items especially for Udyr will make a considerable difference and this will make your calculations more complex.

Comment: In short: there are no defined answers, due to an over-abundance of interacting factors.

Comment: correct. that is the best sentence ever !!!!