# Ancient Golem Stats

Tags: league-of-legends

It seems that answering this [question about jungling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16394/jungling-on-paper-udyr) theory is not trivial. I decided then to try gathering more info, to make it easier to answer it later.

So, which are the stats of Ancient Golem and the little 2 golems that are with him?

I would like to know:

- Hit Points
- Health Regen (1s/5s)
- Damage
- Attack Speed
- Critical Chance
- Armor
- Magic Resistance

All data are important, if I would like to try do some theory calculations.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier just to record how many hits/how much time you need with an optimized rune setup? with things like this its best to stay as close to praxis as possible i presume ...

Comment: I would like to approach the topic using from a theory perspective, if  possible. It would help me and others to build datasheets or programs that can help junglers.

Answer (score 5):

The [Ancient Golem](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_Golem) stats:

- Health: **1450** + **175 per minute**
- Attack Speed: **0.613/sec**
- Damage: **110**
- Critical Chance: **0%**
- Armor: **24**
- Magic Resistance: **0**

The two minions that follow him, are in fact [Young Lizard's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Young_Lizard):

- Health: **350**
- Attack Speed: **0.679/sec**
- Damage: **18**
- Critical Chance: **0%**
- Armor: **8**
- Magic Resistance: **0**

Note: I couldn't find any information, about the health regeneration.

Comment: Health Regen on Neutral Mobs is non-trivial (i.e., it exists) because of how helpful ignite is vs. the largest mobs, Baron Nashor and the Dragon. It's going to be remarkably hard to determine through testing too, short of simply extracting the relative information from the game client itself.

Comment: It would really helpful at least a rough estimation of health regen, at least for the Ancient Golem

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've verified that Health / 5 for the ancient golem varies with time, same as health -- I'm betting it's some flat percentage. However, my experimentations were not exact, and I do not have perfect data for you.

What I *can* tell you is that Health and mana regen at approximately .5 second "tics". At the beginning of the game, the ancient golem ticks 2 four times, and then 3 once, for an approximate regen of 11 / 2.5 seconds, or ~22 health / 5. At the end of my 40 minute practice game, the ancient golem was healing at a rate of alternating 3's and 4's, or an approximate regen of 35 health / 5.

So it doesn't scale *that* much, but it does scale. If someone has better data, or better metrics, please let me know. I'm going to hypothesize that the golem's true regeneration is somewhere on the order of 1.5% of max health. Hopefully, that's close enough to the real thing that you can complete your simulation.

Comment: Thank you for the investigation, I will mark it answered as soon as I can confirm the values are correct. In the meanwhile you got the bounty